# Email deliverability check without sending an email or checking without SMTP

Tags: validation, email, smtp

Here is the scenario. I am using PHP and I want to check whether an email address is valid and deliverable. Here are the steps I take:

1. Validate email address via regex
2. Validate email address via php filter_var
3. Finally use SMTP to check whether the recipient exists

This thing works perfectly except that using an SMTP way is too slow and takes anywhere between 10 seconds to 40 seconds to validate. Sometimes the SMTP check is blocked by the recipient server and my server ip was blacklisted which made all the emails to that server as invalid.

There are professional services out there which do this for you but I don't want to use them for this particular project I am doing. Due to restrictions I cannot actually send an email to that email address.

Is there anyother way or faster way to validate the email addresses? How do these professional email validating companies do the validations so fast and cheaply?

I apologise if the question is not right for this forum. Please tell me and I will promptly delete this. I am new to stackoverflow.

P.S: I checked the other questions but they all pointed to using SMTP as the solution which I am already doing.